# Update all select drop-downs with value

Tags: jquery

I am currently using

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#chkall').on('click', function(){        
      $("select[name='daya[]'] option:eq(1)").prop("selected", "selected");
    });
});
</script>
```

And it works, however, I have 10 select drop-down boxes on the page, all called daya[] - the above function is only updating the first drop-down on the page. Probably something really simple I am missing?

Comment: Why do you have multiple selects with the same name?

Comment: Because it is generated within an array from PHP/MySQLi and updated as such...

Comment: Sorry to revisit this but can anyone help? I wish to update all drop down boxes on a page that are generated called daya[]. I only want to select the option "YES" in all drop downs which have no selection (If they have "NO" selected I want them to stay as they are). All drop downs are called the same but update per membership ID on a final update. Which is why they're called the same.